# How can I provide overload info in hover info in my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I made a hover provider for my extension, and it works well. It shows the overloads of the method that is hovered by the cursor. But I'd like to add arrows to scroll the list of overloads, like in all popular language extensions. Here is the example:
[image: The format I want]

How can I format my hover provider like this?

I tried to look for something like this in official documentation, on forums, and I even tried to ask GPT-4 about it. I didn't find any information about such a function.

Comment: GPT-4 can't give you new stuff, it is just a smart parrot

Comment: Did you consider implementing a `SignatureHelpProvider` instead? I never implemented one myself, so not sure if this would solve your problem, however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shown in your screenshot isn't coming from a `HoverProvider`. It's coming from a [`SignatureHelpProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SignatureHelpProvider), which you will need to implement to get what you want. I don't think there's similar functionality existing for `HoverProvider` at the time of this writing.

The screenshot you've shown is coming from VS Code's builtin `typescript-language-features` extension. See its [`hover.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/languageFeatures/hover.ts) file if you want a reference point.